# Proof two cosets are equal by using the same sets proof method

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am stuck with following proof (abstract algebra):

Proof that the left coset $-2+3\mathbb{Z}$ is equal to the left coset $1+3\mathbb{Z}$ by using the "same set proof method".

Thus far I have the following start:

*) Proof $[-2+3\mathbb{Z}] \subseteq [1+3\mathbb{Z}]$ 
Suppose $z_1\in[-2+3\mathbb{Z}]$, then $z_1 = -2+3k_1$ with $k_1\in \mathbb{Z}$ and 
Suppose $z_2\in[1+3\mathbb{Z}]$, then $z_2 = 1+3k_2$ with $k_2\in \mathbb{Z}$

but then I don't know how to go on. 
Who can give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: So you need to show that also $z_1$ can be written on the form $1 + 3k_3$ and $z_2$ can be written as $-2 + 3k_4$ for suitable $k_3$ and $k_4$.

Comment: OK Thanks! Sometimes it's so easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $-2+3k_{1}$ as $1+3(k_1-1)$ and $1+3k_2$ as $-2+3(k_2+1)$.